# STS unable to create spring stater project

Tags: spring-tools-4

Hai I just installed the **Spring Tool Suite version 4.8.1** and even configured JDK 11 im unable to create a spring stater project since im getting a popup **could not download javadocs and sources**

Comment: Can you share more details? Usually the javadocs and sources are downloaded for Maven projects after the project got created in order to allow you to browse the source code for the libraries in your projects dependencies. But it should not prevent you from working with the project in case that download fails. In any case it would be good to share a few more details, like the exact error message.

Comment: got it, Thank you

Comment: @Meghana Can you explain how did you resolve this issue?